# Why I don't see the difference between two different files in insert mode in vim?

Tags: vim, newlines

Let's create two files:

```
$ echo -n 'test' > test.txt
$ wc test.txt 
0 1 4 test.txt
```

The file `test.txt` doesn't contain the trailing newline.

```
$ echo 'test' > test_n.txt
$ wc test_n.txt 
1 1 5 test_n.txt
```

The file `test_n.txt` contains the trailing newline.

The above two files are obviously different, but the preview of both files in `vim` in *insert mode* does not contain any differences:

```
$ vim test.txt
```

[image]

```
$ vim test_n.txt
```

[image]

Why is there no difference (new line or some special distinction)?

And what can I do to add or remove such an additional character in `vim` in *insert mode*?

Comment: ":set list" would show the difference, and there's a mode which you can inspect.  Both are in the help-files.

Comment: Thank you @ThomasDickey I didn't know this option before.

Comment: @ThomasDickey if you want to add an answer it will be probably the accepted answer. Thank you.

Comment: There's also [`set eol?`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'eol') and if you include a status line ([`set laststatus=2`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'laststatus')), the default format includes `[noeol]` for files missing a trailing newline.

Comment: @filbranden please don't post answers in comments. Answers in comments cannot be voted on by the community and don't mark the question as answered.

Comment: @ThomasDickey see above. Please post that as an answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

vim has a *mode* ["eol"](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'eol') (for end-of-line) to tell what to if the last line in the file lacks a *newline* character.  You can see all of the mode settings in vim (or any program like vi) by

```
:set all
```

[POSIX vi](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/vi.html) does not have a feature for this: files are either zero-length, or **have** a trailing newline.  That's because POSIX vi only deals with text files, which by definition are lines that end with newlines.  In a quick check, nvi and elvis do not have modes for this.  In my comment, I had forgotten a detail of vim: unlike vile, a ":set list" does not readily show the missing newline.  Here's what I see in vim:

```
ssss$
test$
~
~
```

while in vile:

```
ssss^J
test
~
~
```

For either editor, you can read the file in, change the *mode*, e.g.,

```
:set noeol
```

and write the file out, to get a newline on the updated file.  Rather than showing it directly, you can modify the [status line](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'statusline') of vim to show this information. By default, it does not appear to do this, but some packagers have customized this, e.g.,

```
"foo" [noeol] 2L, 9C                                          1,1           All
```

One of the comments suggests using the ["?" modifier](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#E518) of the **`set`** command, e.g.,

```
:set eol?
```

which might show something like this:

```
noendofline                                                   2,1           All
```

but in insert-mode, that is replaced by

```
-- INSERT --                                                  2,1           All
```

so the *status line* seems the right place to maintain this information.

The features have been there a while:

- The **`eol`** feature first appeared in vim 2.4 (July 1994), according to a comment in its source code.
- vile's **`newline`** mode appeared in [July 1993](https://invisible-island.net/vile/CHANGES.R3.html#v3_56:).

([nvi, elvis, vim and vile](https://invisible-island.net/vile/vile.faq.html) all handle *binary* files in addition to the POSIX vi's *text* files).

Comment: almost 20 years using vim, and I still learn new things about it.  and I'm still scared of emacs. :D

Comment: In vim, you can also do [`:set eol?`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#E518) to see whether eol is on or off, so you don't have to look through all the output of `:set all`.

Comment: A less confusing way of saying "files are either zero-length, or have a trailing newline" is "all lines end with a newline, and a text file is a sequence of zero or more lines".